# Wordpress child theme vrs copy theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am deciding between using a child theme vrs a copy of a parent theme.

I know the rule is to use child always. My prob is that I'm changing basically every file and css page in it significantly. (it's a beginner theme so it's not all that much) it seems easier just to copy the whole theme and hack it up.

It's an older theme (2yrs old) so I don't see it being updated to much. Is there a way to 'detach' it from updates so if one occurs it won't screw it up?

I'm not to worried about hackers etc on my simple site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable theme update notifications you can do it by changing the `Theme Name` field in the main style.css, or if you don't wanna change the name the other option is changing its version number to something really high.

```
/*
Theme Name: Your Theme Name
Author: Your Name
Author URI: Your URL
Description: Your theme description
Version: 1.0
*/
```

Comment: Is there any huge ramifications from doing that. I Got the the theme from a site written in like 2011, not intensive at all but I don't want it worry about all the 'security risks' from not updating, etc

Comment: Not at all, for security reasons you should rather care about updating WordPress core. Theme updating is meant to improve it, extend features, etc. but in your case I guess its going to be your internal ongoing process.